# Slick Carousel's height drops to zero after changing routes AND resizing window

Tags: vue.js, slick.js

The (adoptive) height of the slick slider drops to 0px when I switch to another route/component of the vue.js app AND resize the window (e.g. from portrait to landscape orientation). Otherwise it works fine.

Any ideas how to resize it back to full height without destroying/unslick slick and loading all the images again?

here it works fine:
[image]

but here it fails:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it work. Found the right slick property/method in the source code of its Github Repo:

```
updated(){
    window.homeslick = $('#home_slick_slider .inner-container').slick({
            dots: true,
            lazyLoad: "ondemand",
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            prevArrow: false,
            nextArrow: false,
            fade: false,
            adaptiveHeight: true,
        });
},
activated(){
    if(window.homeslick){
        homeslick.slick("refresh");
    }
}
```

Don't understand why they didn't described the existence and syntax of this method properly in the doc file...